# Why are my Crystal Reports 2008 Reports ignoring parameters at runtime?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I've recently updated a project's Crystal Reports documents to the latest version (CR2008), these are the regular reports built into Visual Studio 2010 after installing Crystal Reports free version.

Having updated the reports, they wouldn't ask for parameters within a Windows Forms application. I managed to solve this by simply adding the parameter to the report so it was displayed (I assume this somehow refreshed the fact that there was a parameter available!).

However, the viewer now asks for the parameter but appears to ignore it when the report actually loads.

Has anyone got any ideas? I don't really want to have to make a parameter GUI for every single report and then pass them all through!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the viewer control with the updated one appears to have solved the problem, even though they were both reading from the same reference!